# Magento 1.9: Simple Product is not adding To Cart programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

When I try to add the product to cart programmatically then give an error

> The product could not be found.

Here is my code for product add to cart programmatically.

```
$productId = 2783;
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$params = array('product' => $productId ,'qty' => 1);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($productId);
print_r($product->getId());
$cart->addProduct($product,$params);
$cart->save();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: is your product is Configurable Product? Or product with options?

Comment: Simple product with no option

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to add a product to the cart programmatically.

> Simple product with out options

```
$prod_id = 2783; // pass product id
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
$params = array(
   'product' => $prod_id,
   'qty' => 1,
   'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
);

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$cart->save();

$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

> Simple product with options

```
$productId = "Your Product Id"
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$paramater = array('product' => $productId,
                    'qty' => '1',
                    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
                    'options' => $options 
            );       

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

> Configurable product

```
$productId = "Your Product Id"
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$paramater = array('product' => $productId,
                    'qty' => '1',
                    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
                    'supper_attribute' => $options 
            );       

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

**Hope it helps!!!**